# association data in rails model scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope, associations, relation

I have a model named `Post` (blog post) and a model named `Category`. Each post `belongs_to` a category. Each category has an attribute named `retainer` that specifies the amount of time before a post "expires", so for example `movies_category.retainer = 30.days`

What I'm trying to do is create a scope for `Post` that finds all of the posts which are "expired". So for example, assuming I were to hardcode the value of `30.days` and it were to apply to all categories (therefore all posts), the scope would be:

```
scope :expired, lambda { where("posts.created_at < ?", 30.days.ago) }
```

However, instead of hardcoding the value `30.days.ago`, I want to get the `retainer` value from the post's category and base the condition on that, so something like:

```
scope :expired, lambda { where("posts.created_at < ?", 
  Time.now - post.category.retainer) }
```

So put into words: I want to get all of the posts which are expired, and the expiration status is determined by each post's category's retainer value (i.e. posts in the movies category expire in 10 days, posts in the games category expire in 5 days, etc.)

Is this even possible? Would I require some form of join or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
scope :expired, lambda { |retainer| where("posts.created_at < ?", 
  Time.now - retainer) }
```

Then just use it like:

```
Post.expired(post.category.retainer)
```

Or from the category model like:

```
def Posts
  Post.expired(retainer)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know, something doesn't seem right. Post.expired is supposed to give me expired posts, regardless of what category they're in. If I do Post.expired(post.category.retainer), wouldn't that be counting only one posts' category?

Comment: I don't think that will work with your current structure.  If you update the expired_at on the post whenever it's association with category changes (or, if you update the category and push it through to any posts) it'll be pretty simple and that would be my recommendation.

Comment: Okay, so you're saying it's probably easier to maintain an expires_at attribute on the post, than to keep a retainer attribute on the category. Thanks for the idea, I'll think about it.

Comment: This was ultimately what I ended up doing. Thanks