# ActiveRecord, how to trigger a process when column time is met

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's assume that we have a table, Product

```
+---+------+--------+--------------+
| id|  name| status | expiry_date  |
+---+------+--------+--------------+
| 1 |   A  | Good   | 10 min ago   | <-- this supposed to be "Expired"
| 2 |   B  | Good   | 10 min later | 
+---+------+--------+--------------+
```

My question is how to set the status of id 1 to "Expired" because it expiry date is passed.

I usually did this with cron task. However, reading entire table to find few rows are not efficient I think, and furthermore, a cron task does not update status until its interval comes.(i.e. 10min, 20min.. etc)

Is there any way to trigger an immediate process when a time is met, so that I can update its status as soon as possible?

Hope my question is clear.

Comment: you can create a scope 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456278/association-data-in-rails-model-scope

Answer (score 0):

If you imply a controller's action in which you would like to do the update, you can do the following:

```
Product.where(["expire_date < ?", ->{ Time.now.utc - 10.minutes }.call]).update_all(:status, 'Bad')
```

**Updated.** OR  if you only would like to update a single product with a given ID:

```
product = Product.find(params[:id])

if product.expire_date < Time.now.utc - 10.minutes
  product.status = 'Bad'
  product.save
end
```